# How to turn off SSL in django database settings

Tags: python, django, ssl

How can I turn off in the django database settings.

I've tried things like:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '??',
        'USER': '??',
        'PASSWORD': '??',
        'HOST': '??',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'SSL' :0
    }
}
```

and

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '??',
        'USER': '??',
        'PASSWORD': '??',
        'HOST': '??',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS' : {'SSL' : 0}
    }
}
```

but neither of these work.

Comment: I guess SSL is not turned on by default, so just remove that option.

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded my mysql to 5.6.27 and that worked.